# how to add animation to textView drawable

Tags: android, animation, drawable

I have used this line too add image in my textView : `android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_launcher"`
in my xml file.

```
   <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:drawablePadding="5dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:text="@string/hello_world"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    >

</TextView>
```

Now I want to add animation to this drawable.
I dont know how can I access this image.

Any help?
thanks in advance

Comment: use setCompoundDrawables, it seems there is no getter for compound drawables

Comment: can you explain a little more?? how should I use this?

Comment: use setCompoundDrawables( Drawable left, Drawable top, Drawable right, Drawable bottom) pass null for top, right and bottom Drawable, that way you set only left Drawable

Answer (score 17, accepted):

if you set the drawable in the XML, you won't be able to access it like you can with an `ImageView`'s `getDrawable()`. Instead, omit it from your XML and do it in your `Activity/Fragment`:

```
TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
AnimationDrawable d = (AnimationDrawable) getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
tv.setCompoundDrawables(d, null, null, null);
d.start();
```

Provided your drawable `ic_launcher` can be animated like an [AnimationDrawable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/AnimationDrawable.html), this should start the animation. Call `d.stop()` to cease animation.

Comment: Can you please show the drawable you've used? And how can I invert the animation ?

Answer (score 11):

To make simple animations like rotation you can do something like this:

Assume `@drawable/ic_launcher` is a drawable you want to animate.
Define `some_drawable.xml` with the appropriate values:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <rotate
            android:drawable="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:pivotX="50%"
            android:pivotY="50%"
            android:fromDegrees="0"
            android:toDegrees="180" />
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Assign this drawable as a compound one to your TextView:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:drawablePadding="5dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:text="@string/hello_world"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/some_drawable"
    >
```

To start animation:

```
int MAX_LEVEL = 10000;

Drawable[] myTextViewCompoundDrawables = myTextView.getCompoundDrawables();
for(Drawable drawable: myTextViewCompoundDrawables) {

    if(drawable == null)
        continue;

    ObjectAnimator anim = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(drawable, "level", 0, MAX_LEVEL);
    anim.start();
}
```

Comment: Where does the 10000 come from?

Comment: It's over 9000!

Comment: @androiddeveloper Because drawable level can be max 10000

Comment: @MirecXP Why does it have a max? Is it documented? Can't we do it without this max? After all, some Drawables are supposed to be played forever...