# how to display the image inside the button and image will be blink animation

Tags: android

> 1

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="16dp"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="71dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/coloryellow1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Alok International School"
            android:textSize="10pt"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/iv1"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/iv1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="14dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="14dp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/logo64"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_width="357dp"
        android:layout_height="125dp"
        android:background="@drawable/colorlogin">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/p1"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

        <TextView
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textStyle="normal"
            android:textSize="25dp"
            android:textColor="#EEFFFF"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="ALOK SHARMA"
            android:paddingLeft="15dp"
            android:id="@+id/textView8"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:id="@+id/line1">

            <Button
                android:layout_width="160dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:background="@drawable/circle"
                android:drawableTop="@drawable/profile"
                android:paddingTop="20dp"
                android:text="Profile"
                android:id="@+id/btnprofile"
                android:textColor="#fff" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="160dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/circle1"
                android:id="@+id/btnattendance"
                android:drawableTop="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_map"
                android:paddingTop="20dp"
                android:text="Attendance"
                android:textColor="#fff" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <Button
                android:layout_width="160dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:background="@drawable/circle2"
                android:drawableTop="@drawable/notice"
                android:paddingTop="20dp"
                android:text="Notice"
                android:id="@+id/btnnotice"
                android:textColor="#fff" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="160dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/circle3"
                android:drawableTop="@drawable/talk"
                android:paddingTop="20dp"
                android:text="Talk"
                android:id="@+id/btntalk"
                android:textAllCaps="true"
                android:textColor="#fff" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <Button
                android:layout_width="160dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:background="@drawable/circle4"
                android:drawableTop="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email"
                android:paddingTop="20dp"
                android:text="Today food"
                android:id="@+id/btntoday_food"
                android:textColor="#fff" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="160dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/circle5"
                android:drawableTop="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_map"
                android:paddingTop="20dp"
                android:text="fees"
                android:id="@+id/btnfees"
                android:textColor="#fff" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

> 2

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="16dp"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="71dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/coloryellow1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Alok International School"
            android:textSize="10pt"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/iv1"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/iv1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="14dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="14dp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/logo64"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_width="357dp"
        android:layout_height="125dp"
        android:background="@drawable/colorlogin">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/p1"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

        <TextView
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textStyle="normal"
            android:textSize="25dp"
            android:textColor="#EEFFFF"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="ALOK SHARMA"
            android:paddingLeft="15dp"
            android:id="@+id/textView8"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:id="@+id/line1">

            <Button
                android:layout_width="160dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:background="@drawable/circle"
                android:drawableTop="@drawable/profile"
                android:paddingTop="20dp"
                android:text="Profile"
                android:id="@+id/btnprofile"
                android:textColor="#fff" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="160dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/circle1"
                android:id="@+id/btnattendance"
                android:drawableTop="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_map"
                android:paddingTop="20dp"
                android:text="Attendance"
                android:textColor="#fff" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <Button
                android:layout_width="160dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:background="@drawable/circle2"
                android:drawableTop="@drawable/notice"
                android:paddingTop="20dp"
                android:text="Notice"
                android:id="@+id/btnnotice"
                android:textColor="#fff" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="160dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/circle3"
                android:drawableTop="@drawable/talk"
                android:paddingTop="20dp"
                android:text="Talk"
                android:id="@+id/btntalk"
                android:textAllCaps="true"
                android:textColor="#fff" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <Button
                android:layout_width="160dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:background="@drawable/circle4"
                android:drawableTop="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email"
                android:paddingTop="20dp"
                android:text="Today food"
                android:id="@+id/btntoday_food"
                android:textColor="#fff" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="160dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/circle5"
                android:drawableTop="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_map"
                android:paddingTop="20dp"
                android:text="fees"
                android:id="@+id/btnfees"
                android:textColor="#fff" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

I want to visualize a `ImageView` inside the `Button`, but image is not showing inside the `Button` why?

[image]

and this image should be blink...

layout of this code ..now i want to that
  android:drawableTop="@drawable/profile"
   in this code profile picture should be blink animation...

Comment: check the drawable part of a button

Comment: refer [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33015797/5148289)

Answer (score 2):

you can use   `android:drawableTop=""` of button like this

```
    <Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_calender"
    android:text="button 5" />
```

**or this create a new layout like this**

```
    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/linear"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:src="@drawable/disha2" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="abc" />
</LinearLayout>
```

set click listner to linearlayout like this

```
 // Animation
Animation animFadein;
LinearLayout linearLayout = findViewById(R.id.linear);
    linearLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // load the animation
    animFadein = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),
            R.anim.fade_in);
         Imageview.startAnimation(animFadein);
        }
    });
```

get animation as per your requirement [from here](https://www.androidhive.info/2013/06/android-working-with-xml-animations/)

Comment: but i want to blink the only icon.not whole button

Comment: thank you can use a linearlayout inside it use imagebutton and textview and set click event of linearlayout

Comment: i write this code but image not showing.. <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/subji"
                    android:id="@+id/img"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>
                </LinearLayout>

Comment: set background of linear laout

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 final Animation animation = new AlphaAnimation(0.3f, 1.0f);
 animation.setDuration(1000);
 layout_id.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v) {
                                imageview_id.startAnimation(animation);     
                            }
                        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `LinearLayout` with `clickable="true"` and `background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"` to achieve default click effect, and add `ImageView` and `TextView` inside it

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="20dp">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:src="@drawable/icon" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="Button1" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: but when i  set the own create a color xml but..then image is not showing..

Answer (score 0):

I would first suggest you create a `layout` instead of using a `button`

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:src="@drawable/image" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="TextView1" />
   </LinearLayout>
```

Now, you can flash(fade in) the `ImageView` using the below code.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);

Animation myFadeInAnimation;

 ImageView myImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image); 

    Animation myFadeInAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(null, R.anim.fade_in);

//use this below line whenever you want to blink your icon
 myImageView.startAnimation(myFadeInAnimation);
}
```

Now create a `fade_in.xml` in anim folder.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"> 
    <alpha android:fromAlpha="0.0" 
    android:toAlpha="1.0" 
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"  
    android:duration="50" android:repeatCount="infinite"/> 
 </set>
```

If you are not satisfied with fade in animation just google out animations that would get your effect that you look for.

Comment: For which element you have added background color?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
 <Button
android:id="@+id/btn"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_calender"
android:text="button 5" />

final Animation animation = new AlphaAnimation(1, 0);
    animation.setDuration(500);
    animation.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
    animation.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
    animation.setRepeatMode(Animation.REVERSE);


    btn.startAnimation(animation);
```