# Setting a Circular ProgressBar as a Left Drawable to a TextView programatically

Tags: android, android-animation, android-xml, android-drawable, android-progressbar

I have a **progressbar_text** `TextView`:

```
<TextView  
 android:id="progressbar_text"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
/>
```

and a **custom_animated_shape.xml** as:

```
<animated-rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:fromDegrees="270"
        android:toDegrees="270">
    <shape
        android:innerRadius="20dp"
        android:innerRadiusRatio="2.5"
        android:shape="ring"
        android:thickness="5dp"
        android:useLevel="true">

        <gradient
            android:angle="0"
            android:endColor="@color/foo_color"
            android:startColor="@color/foo_color"
            android:type="sweep"
            android:useLevel="false"/>
    </shape>
</animated-rotate>
```

Setting it as:

```
progressbar_text.setCompoundDrawablesRelativeWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.custom_animated_shape, 0, 0, 0)
```

wont work

**Is there any way to set a *circular progress* bar as a `Left Drawable` to a `TextView`?**

Comment: Try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21787958/how-to-add-animation-to-textview-drawable.

Answer (score -1):

Try below code,you can wrap your textview and progressbar inside linearlayout.

```
 <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/progress_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_height="20dp">
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="20dp"
                    android:textColor="#000"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:text="Progress bar at right."/>
                <ProgressBar
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="20dp"
                    style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Small"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5dp" />
            </LinearLayout>
```